# Differences with formatting options in IE11 with Date.toLocaleDateString()?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internationalization, ecmascript-intl

I have a simple issue that I don't know how to fix. If I run this code in Chrome:

```
var event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 5, 3, 0, 0));
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options));
```

The result is `Tuesday, December 4, 2012` but if I run it in IE11 I get `‎Tuesday‎, ‎December‎ ‎04‎, ‎2012`.

It seems that IE11 is not conforming to the format argument of `day: 'numeric'` and instead acts as if I specified `day: '2-digit'`.

So is this just IE11's fault? I couldn't find any discussion of this specific issue online. If it is, how can I work around this to get the formatting I want without the leading 0 on single-digit day numbers?

Comment: I checked your code in IE11 console. It is giving out date without appending 0. Here is the output: ‎Wednesday‎, ‎December‎ ‎5‎, ‎2012

Comment: @VikasArora That's interesting! What version are you using? I am on Version 11.0.9600.18665 with "Update Versions" at 11.0.42. I noticed your output was December 5 instead of 4... maybe you have a different system language or locale than me?